# Causes of busybox brop

Tags: linux-mint, startup, busybox

At what seemed a random moment (nothing special was happening to my knowledge), all my files where suddenly read-only.

After rebooting, my Linux Mint 20 doesn't start and drops to busybox, with this message:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/psparse-330)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PEGP.DD02._BCL due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

So, what may cause busybox to start here?

How can I boot on Mint from here?

Comment: What motherboard and which BIOS version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many solution found indicated that I should do fsck on my boot partition from busybox, which didn't work (hence my question here)

The problem was that I use LVM, so instead of `fsck /dev/sda5`, I had to do `fsck /dev/mint-vg/` and it worked.

This solution was indicated on busybox, when typing `exit`, a few gibberish messages appeared, and among them `run fsck /dev/mint-vg/ to solve problem`

Still no hint on why it happened though.